# What are Neville, Seamus, and McGonagall talking about blowing up?

Tags: movie, harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2*, the following exchange occurs:

> Neville Longbottom: Are you really giving us permission to do this?
>   Minerva McGonagall: Yes, Longbottom.
>   Neville Longbottom: Blow it up? Boom?
>   Minerva McGonagall: BOOM!
>   Minerva McGonagall: Why don't you confer with Mr. Finnigan? As I recall, he has a particular proclivity for pyrotechnics.
>   Seamus Finnigan: I can bring it down!
>   Minerva McGonagall: That's the spirit, now away you go.

Is it ever made clear what McGonagall is giving them permission to blow up?

Comment: You mean like shortly after, when they blow something up?

Answer (score 33):

I thought it was fairly obvious that they were talking about the bridge where Neville taunts the werewolves and closely escapes death. Any reason to assume otherwise?

Comment: Werevolves? I thought they were bounty hunters.

Comment: One of which is a werewolf; Fenrir Greyback meets his fate in the movie at that bridge, while in the book his fate is uncertain.

Comment: that was a snatcher that died on bridge not greyback. same fellow in the woods who smelled hermoines perfume.

Comment: Greyback is alive after the bridge scene, when he chows down on lavender. Nom nom nom

Answer (score 9):

The film's [screenplay](https://www.scribd.com/doc/163084623/HARRY-POTTER-AND-THE-DEATHLY-HALLOWS-PART-2-by-screenplay-Steve-Kloves) makes it pretty clear that Neville and co. were speaking about blowing up the [wooden bridge](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wooden_Bridge), the rearward entrance to Hogwarts Castle.

> **PROFESSOR McGONAGALL:** *Why don't you confer with Mr. Finnegan? As I recall, he has a particular proclivity for pyrotechnics.*
>
> Neville and Ginny glance back at Seamus.
>
> **SEAMUS:** *I can bring 'er down.*
>
> **PROFESSOR McGONAGALL:** *That's the spirit. Now off you go.*

In the following scene, they're doing precisely that, setting charges onto the wooden bridge. Note that this the screen direction is "***continuous action***" indicating that they've not been anywhere else since we last saw them, followed by "***moments later***".

> 235B - EXT. WOODEN BRIDGE - CONTINUOUS ACTION - NIGHT     Further on,
>   small as ants from this vantage, Neville, Ginny, Seamus and half a
>   dozen DA members approach the WOODEN BRIDGE.
>
> ...
>
> 242 EXT. WOODEN BRIDGE - NIGHT (MOMENTS LATER)
>
> Neville limps into our FIELD OF VIEW and peers outward, marveling at
>   the bombardment above.
>
> **SEAMUS**: *That's it. I want a charge on each and every joist.*
>
> Neville peers below. Down amongst the pilings, Seamus directs KATIE
>   BELL, CHO and NIGEL in placing magical "charges" (spells) on key
>   pressure points.
>
> **NEVILLE:** *You do know what you're doing, don't you, Seamus?*
>
> Seamus winks, gives a thumbs-up — he seems to be enjoying himself,
>   perhaps inordinately so. Neville exhales, shakes his head.
>
> **NEVILLE:** *Blimey*